# Use tcpdump to find all packets in and out and the interface used for each

Tags: linux, router, routing

I would like to debug the routing behaviour on a Linux box working as a router.

What I'm looking for is the equivalent to `tcpdump` which can show me all IP packets going in and out of my box along the corresponding interfaces being used.

I'm familiar with displaying the routing table and how `ip route get` works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mistaken that tcpdump operates at layer 4. It has retained the name from decades ago, but even the default mode will show you the L3 IP header (which *is* the "routing information"). Add `-n` to disable the DNS lookups and show raw numeric IP addresses. Add `-e` to also show the link-layer header (with L2 MAC addresses, VLAN tags, etc.)

The only thing it cannot do is monitor several interfaces *at once* – you need to have several windows, one interface each. (The graphical Wireshark does support multi-interface capture.)